# Is it okay to specify some interactions before all main effects in a linear model (and ANOVA?)

Tags: regression, anova

I would like to specify some interaction terms before all main effects in a linear model, but am finding it difficult to do in R, so I am wondering if there is a statistical reason why I shouldn't? The reason for specifying the order in the model is that next I want to use a type I ANOVA to investigate the effects of different variables.

I want this model:
`y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2 + x3 + x1:x3 + x2:x3 + x1:x2:x3`

But R insists on this model (no matter what order I type the terms in)*:
`y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x1:x2 + x1:x3 + x2:x3 + x1:x2:x3`

The purpose of using the first model and a type I ANOVA would be to account for all variance explained by `x1` and `x2` before seeing if any remaining variance is explained by `x3`. Is there any reason why I shouldn't be trying to do this?

**Updates:**

1. Actually it is [not that hard to do in R.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68007332/can-the-order-of-main-effect-vs-interaction-terms-in-lm-in-r-be-specified)
2. Maybe it helps to specify that in my case, x1 and x2 are factors and x3 is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to look at variance for x1 and x2 before x3 as long as you have the 3-factor interaction-term. Changing the order is only relevant if you remove the all interaction-terms with x1, x3 and x2, x3.

Comment: So I should be able to have `y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2 + x3 + x1:x3 + x2:x3`? Or just `y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2 + x3`?

Comment: You should be able to do y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2 + x3

Comment: Thanks - this is a useful answer, but a little more explanation on why would be helpful to people like me with a rather fuzzy understanding of what goes on behind an ANOVA :)

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to Kirsten's answer, to get this to work in R you need to paste the two vectors together

```
x1x2 <- paste0(x1,x2)
y~x1+x2+x1x2+x3
```

otherwise anova will still put the interaction term last.

Comment: Turns out you can also use a `terms` object, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68007332/can-the-order-of-main-effect-vs-interaction-terms-in-lm-in-r-be-specified?noredirect=1#comment120201911_68007332) :)